# Where is "\u202f" in printed string?

Tags: python, python-unicode

I have a file **test.tsv** contains special symbol **"\u202f"**:
[special symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8Ics.jpg)

When i wrote a python script to read this file, found that **.readline()** and read this symbol, and **.read()** can not read it.

And when i print **lines1[0]**, **"\u202f"** disappeared.

**Why ?**

Code:

```
ff = "test.tsv"

lines1 = open(ff, encoding='utf-8').readlines()
str1 = open(ff, encoding='utf-8').read()

print("lines1:", lines1)
print("lines1[0]:", lines1[0])
print("str1:", str1)
```

Output:

```
lines1: ['assume Fourbooks\u202f è una piattaforma\n']
lines1[0]: assume Fourbooks  è una piattaforma

str1: assume Fourbooks  è una piattaforma
```

Comment: What did you expect it to show?

Answer (score 2):

First of all both `readline()` and `read()` are reading your special character.

The `readline()` reads each line as it is present in the file and append it to the list, on the other hand `read()` reads all the content of your file and save it is as a string.

If you see your output closely, you will notice that while printing `lines1` you are getting `\u202f` as a text only not as a evaluated value. But when you are printing `lines1[0]` and `str1`, your special character is getting printed but this time it's value is getting evaluated which is a whitespace.

The actual reason behind the difference in the output is that the `__repr__` function is being called (through the list, on line `print(lines1)`, and in the other, the `__str__` function is being called (by the str object itself, on lines `print(lines1[0])` and `print(str1)`) as mentioned in the comments by [MZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7871685/m-z)